# Multer express not return filename outside function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I tried to use multer middleware to upload image and get image name outside of the function. It didn't return my filename but when I use `console.log` inside the function it returns file name.

Here is my Controller in express I call **upload** function

```
const uploadData = await utils.uploads.uploadImage('myImage', req);
```

here is my uploadImage

```
static async uploadImage(imgName, req, res ) {
   //call function setupPath
    const setupPath = await this.setupPath();
    try {
        let upload = await  multer({ storage: setupPath }).single(imgName);
        const storeImage = await this.storeImage(upload, req, res);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(`try/catch(${e})`);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my function setupPath

```
static async setupPath() {
      const setup = await multer.diskStorage({
                       destination: './public/uploads/',
                       filename: function (req, file, cb) {
                       cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)); }
                    })
        return setup;
}
```

Here is my StoreImage function  this is the problem that I `console.log` **req.file** -> it returns file data but when I `console.log` outside the function it's undefined

```
static async storeImage(upload, req, res) {
    const uploads = await upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            // res.send(err);
            return 'y';
        } else {
            console.log(req.file) // here return data
            var file = req.file
        }
    })

    console.log(file) // here return undefined
     return uploads;
}
```

How can I get **var file** outside the function ?

Comment: try to log req.file instead of file and check what it prints

Comment: It's return undefinedI cant log req.file outside multer because body-parser doesn't support form-data

Comment: isn't it logical that outside the function the file will return `undefined`. As you can see `req.file` is existed in `uploads` function scope. Outside this scope, file will get `undefined` value. And why you need the `file` outside the function? Your question is not clear

Comment: I need file  ( filename ) to save it into database and yes req.file is in upload function that's why I use var to declared variable is their anyway to get req.file out of upload function ? @InsaneDA